# Email Duplicate Percentage calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, window-functions

I have a table like below

```
email            table_name
a@mail.com         a1
a@mail.com         b2
b@mail.com         a1
c@mail.com         c1
d@mail.com         d1
e@mail.com         e
g@mail.com         e
g@mail.com         e
e@mail.com         f
g@mail.com         g
```

So from here how can I calculate email duplicate percentage of each table

```
table_name total_email  duplicate_email  duplicate_percentage
a1           2                1             50%
b2           1                1             100%
c1           1                0             0
d1           1                0             0
e            2                2             100%
f            1                1             100%
g            1                1             100%
```

Comment: Your expected results don't make sense (at least to me). Why `b2 1 1 100%`? (and others).

Comment: @forpas b2 has email a@mail.com and it is duplicated in table a1 and emal always will be distinct count so its like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my try. Setup:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    email VARCHAR(100),
    table_name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Test (
    email,
    table_name)
VALUES
    ('a@mail.com', 'a1'),
    ('a@mail.com', 'b2'),
    ('b@mail.com', 'a1'),
    ('c@mail.com', 'c1'),
    ('d@mail.com', 'd1'),
    ('e@mail.com', 'e'),
    ('g@mail.com', 'e'),
    ('g@mail.com', 'e'),
    ('e@mail.com', 'f'),
    ('g@mail.com', 'g')
```

Solution:

```
;WITH DupDetail AS
(
    SELECT
        T.email,
        T.table_name,
        IsDup = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T.email) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        @Test AS T
),
DupStats AS
(
    SELECT
        T.table_name,
        total_email = COUNT(DISTINCT(T.email)),
        duplicate_email = COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN T.IsDup = 1 THEN T.email END))
    FROM
        DupDetail AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.table_name
)
SELECT
    D.table_name,
    D.total_email,
    D.duplicate_email,
    duplicate_percentage = CONVERT(
        DECIMAL(5,2), 
        D.duplicate_email * 100.0 / D.total_email)
FROM
    DupStats AS D
```

`IsDup` column marks the mail as 1 if it's repeated *in any table*, then `duplicate_email` is a `COUNT DISTINCT` for all emails that are duplicates across all tables, but grouped by each table name.

Result:

```
table_name  total_email duplicate_email duplicate_percentage
a1          2           1               50.00
b2          1           1               100.00
c1          1           0               0.00
d1          1           0               0.00
e           2           2               100.00
f           1           1               100.00
g           1           1               100.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions, then aggregation:

```
select 
    table_name,
    sum(cnt1) duplicate,
    sum(1.0 * cnt1) / cnt2 percentage
from (
    select
        t.*,
        count(*) over(partition by email) - 1 cnt1,
        count(*) over(partition by table_name) cnt2
    from mytable t
) t
group by table_name, cnt2
order by table_name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e9fbc76327f1db5f829f26e52c6a7d6)**:

```
table_name | duplicate | percentage
:--------- | --------: | :---------
a1         |         1 | 0.500000  
b2         |         1 | 1.000000  
c1         |         0 | 0.000000  
d1         |         0 | 0.000000
```

Comment: I have edited with more data for better understanding this answer does not give the correct result